# AC sweep on H bridge circuit

Tags: mosfet, motor, ltspice, h-bridge

I built a H bridge circuit and I'm struggling with the analysis part. Below is the H bridge circuit I built. A brief description of the circuit: V1 and V2 both send inverse PWM signals and U1 and U2 are both optocoupler where U3, U4, U5, U6 are MOSFET and the circuit is being powered by a 7.2 volt supply.

[image]

When I run AC sweep I get a result which I don’t  understand. Why does the AC sweep only have two lines one at -240 dB and another at -390 dB. What are the meaning of these lines?

[image]

Comment: Did you actually define what you are sweeping? You have two gate signal sources. We also have no idea what V(n010) is in the schematic.

Comment: @DKNguyen How do i define what i'm sweeping. When i run an ac sweep the only options i have are type of sweep, number of points per decade, start frequency and end frequency. Ignore V(n010) everywhere i click on the circuit i get the same ac result.

Comment: Well, I would start by modifying your circuit to only one gate signal source so you don't need to worry about trying to get LTSPICE to sweep two sources simultaneously in tandem if that is even possible.

Comment: @DKNguyen I appreciate the help. What do you mean by one gate signal source and how can I implement this?

Comment: Right now you have two gate signal generators running in lockstep and they're never intended to run out of lockstep (inversions of each other). That means you can add logic so that everything can just be driven by one source. What would you do if you were building this in real life and couldn't spend another $1000 on a second signal generator or come up with a method to synch them to each other?

Comment: @DKNguyen i tried to use a invertor with one PWM voltage source but no matter what i did i could never get the inverted signal to go up to 5v it would only go up to 1v even when editing the Vhigh and Vlow settings which is why i settled for 2 voltage sources

Comment: Well get that working, or build an inverter if you have to out of a push-pull.

Comment: @DKNguyen i will try to get it work. Final thing how do i define what i'm sweeping when its Ac

Comment: You probably weren't messing that up for just one signal source. You were signal sweeping *something* according to your graph. But I'm not sure if is what you're looking for since I think frequency sweep normally sweeps sinusoids not a square wave. Get the single source working first then you can tinker with it more easily.

Comment: The .AC primitive in a SPICE simulator implies a *linear* circuit not a switching circuit as yours. If you want the ac *small-signal* response of this circuit, you need to a) resort to an average model or b) use a simulator like SIMPLIS which can extract the ac response from a switching circuit. Look at the 60+ [templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) I published which work with the demo version.

Comment: The [link you gave](https://imgur.com/a/LbilBl5) in your previous question says, at point c, to perform an AC sweep, but the description is vague, and hints at changing the signals generated by the Arduino. In that case, it's possible your teacher meant to sweep the PWM duty cycle -- better ask for clarifications. Also, your back EMF is not a *simple* series voltage source (the `V` source), it's a *current controlled* voltage source (the `H` source), to which you need to write `L1 <value>`, where `<value>` is a numeric value for the amount of sensed current (e.g. `L1 0.5`).